# Expected number of jacks drawn given that you draw cards till you draw all 4 kings?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation, conditional-expectation

I don't understand how to solve this. Basically define J as our random variable such that J: {0,1,2,3,4}. To solve this, we need to know the probability of getting e.g., 0 jacks given that we draw cards till we get all 4 kings. I don't understand how to compute this probability. I appreciate hints.

Comment: You could try to compute the expected number of jacks until you get to the first king, and then show that this is the expected number of jacks left over when you get to the fourth king (deal the pack from the other end).

Answer (score 5):

**Hint.** Imagine taking the eight jacks and kings out of the deck, preserving their order.  How likely is it that of these eight cards, the first four cards are kings?  There is only one such arrangement, so the probability is

$$
p_0 = \frac{1}{\binom{8}{4}} = \frac{1}{70}
$$

Now, how likely is it that four of the first five (including the fifth) are kings?  How likely is it that four of the first six (including the sixth) are kings?  Etc.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: However the cards fall they are arranged in the order $xxxKxxxKxxxKxxxKxxx$ where $xxx$ stands for any number of cards from zero to forty eight. The remaining cards are equally likely to be in any of the five $xxx$ slots. What is the average number of jacks per slot?

Comment: But he wants the distribution of the number of jacks, not the expected number.

Comment: @BrianTung The title of the question is "Expected number of jacks ... ". I agree this doesn't give the distribution. The body of the question says "to do this we need to ..." which isn't quite true. Your answer is essentially the same as mine, except with more detail. It may well be that the question intends the detail to be computed.

Comment: Ahh, you are quite right! I didn't pay close enough attention to the title. In that case, your answer short-circuits the need for the distribution quite nicely and arrives at the same answer.

Comment: Thanks Mark and Brian for your response. Ok, so we can solve this applying linearity of expectation over the sequence of xxxKxxxKxxxKxxK. So the expected length of each slot is the same i.e., 13, which intuitively makes sense because there are 4 suits, each with an ace. Within 13 cards, the expected number of jacks is 1 because 4 Jacks:52 cards simplifies to 1:13. So, since there are 4 slots we just sum the expected number of jacks within each slot, thus resulting in 4?

Comment: Kind of.  There are five slots, which must total four jacks.  Therefore, the average number of jacks per slot is what divided by what?  Which leads us to conclude that the average number of jacks in the first four slots is what?